# Full Calendar slow rendering

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working with a legacy codebase that uses full calendar (2.3.1) in a react based portal to display a resource view as seen in the picture attached.

The calendar starts to get very slow whenever i move a date forwards or backwards or select a date from date picker. However this problem arises only when there are a lot of columns in resource view and when there are less columns like 4 or 5, the calendar works perfectly.

Is there a way to improve the performance on this view?

**Here's the code that initalizes the calendar:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
    header: false,
    events: [],
    views: {
      multiColAgendaDay: {
        type: 'multiColAgenda',
        duration: { days: 1 },
        numColumns: employees.length,
        columnHeaders: employees,
      },
    },

    defaultView: defaultView,
    eventMouseover: this.eventMouseover,
    //eventMouseout: this.eventMouseout,
    eventClick: props.onSelectEvent,
    nowIndicator: true,
    dayClick: this.selectTimeSlot,
    eventDrop: this.eventDrop,
    changeView: this.changeView,
    eventResize: this.eventResize,
    windowResize: this.windowResize,
    slotDuration: '00:15',
    axisFormat: 'h:mmA',
    viewRender: this.viewRender,
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventRender: this.eventRender,
    minTime: convert12To24(openingTime, 'hh:mma'),
    maxTime: convert12To24(closingTime, 'hh:mma'),
    businessHours: {
      dow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      start: convert12To24(openingTime, 'hh:mma'),
      end: convert12To24(closingTime, 'hh:mma'),
    },
  });
```

**Change View:**

```
 changeView = view => {
   this.calendarComponent.fullCalendar('changeView', view);
 };
```

**I CAN'T CHANGE THE CURRENT CALENDAR LIBRARY AND HAVE MAKE DO WITH THIS ONLY**

[image: Calendar Resource View]

Comment: What you'll want to do is _virtual rendering_ of the grid. What this means is that you'll only actually render what's on the screen, rather than everything that's in memory. There are many ways to do this. [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) is a popular option

Comment: I can't currently change the library, is there any work around this problem using the current library?

Comment: I've never used the lib before, sorry. Took a quick look at the docs. Maybe you can implement virtual rendering yourself via [`resourceRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceRender). It seems that lets you change the DOM before something is rendered - maybe you can have it render nothing if the resource isn't going to be on the screen

Comment: have you got a lot of events, perhaps? How are you loading events into the calendar, exactly? Are you fetching all your events at once, or just restricting it to the ones which occur within the time period currently shown in the calendar (that is the recommended way). Obviously adding more resources could exacerbate such a problem are more events need to be downloaded and displayed.

Comment: I'm passing it an array of all events! That means the events that could be on the next date or a week later are also being passed on to it.. do you think that could be the case ?

Comment: well it won't be helping, and there's absolutely no need for it. Just return the events which are needed for the time period which is currently on display. In fact fullCalendar can help you with this - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed - if you set your event feed up like that it will supply you with the start and end dates automatically. Or if you can't make your endpoint as compliant as that, do it this way instead, using an intermediary function - but again fullCalendar gives you the right start/end dates to send on to the server. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function